# Query database for an element in an List attribute of a model

Tags: opa

I have the following data model declared:

```
toto = { name : "toto1" tata_list : ["id1", "id2", "id3", ...] }
```

With the OPA database query syntax, can I retrieve the "toto" model that contains a specific "id" in his "tata_list" attribute ?

Something like:

```
myToto = /toto/toto[tata_list contains "id1"]
```

Or do I have to browse all the "toto" and search for each of them if the tata_list attribute contains my ID ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so called "hole expression" in Opa: `[_]`. For the database value of list type:

```
list(anything) /my_db/my_list_val
```

the path `my_list_val[_]` in the query refers to any element of the list.

In chapter [Querying / Sub-queries](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki/The-database#sub-queries) of the manual (in the [WIKI](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki)) the example:

```
dbset(_, _) x = /dbname/complex[smap["key"].lst[_] == "value"]
```

finds the documents based on the `list(string)` value named `lst`. If list (actually, record with string map where key is `"key"` and value is nested record with field `lst`) contains string `"value"`, then it satisfies the search condition.

In your case, the query could be:

```
myToto = /toto/toto[tata_list[_] == "id1"]
```